# Use XSLT to create DAT file

Tags: xml, xslt, newline, flat-file

I have an xslt file which creates a simple flat file.
The output file originally had a .txt extension, but now it needs to be a .dat extension.
Everything was perfect, but once I changed the extension, the .dat file does not interpret the new line character correctly.

Here is my XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"  />
<xsl:strip-space  elements="*"/>

<!-- Output File type is .DAT => This extension uses a different value for new line characters -->
<xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#10;'"/>
<!-- <xsl:variable name='newline'><xsl:text> -->
<!-- </xsl:text></xsl:variable> -->
<xsl:variable name="tab" select="'&#x09;'" />
<xsl:variable name="comma" select="'&#x2C;'" />
<xsl:variable name="padding" select="'                              '" /> <!-- 30 spaces for padding -->
<xsl:variable name="zeroes">00000000000</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="sevzeroes">0000000</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="/ROOT/Payment">

                <!-- Filler -->
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat($padding, $padding), 1, 31)"/>
                <!-- Check Amount -->
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat($zeroes, amount), (1 + string-length(amount)), (11 + string-length(amount)))"/>

                <!-- Credit Indicator -->
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="is_void = 0">
                        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="is_void = 1">
                        <xsl:text>C</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>

                <!-- Filler -->
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <!-- Check Number -->
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat($sevzeroes, check_number), (1 + string-length(check_number)), (7 + string-length(check_number)))"/>

                <!-- Check Date -->
                <!-- Incoming Date Format 2014-03-11-07:00 -->
                <xsl:variable name="firstDate" select="last_printed" />
                <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after($firstDate, '-'), '-'), '-')"/>
                <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring-before(substring-after($firstDate, '-'), '-')"/>
                <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring-before($firstDate, '-')"/>

                <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat($month, $day, $year, $padding), 1, 8)"/>

                <!-- TYPE -->
                <xsl:text>S</xsl:text>
                <!-- Filler -->
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat($padding, $padding), 1, 31)"/>

                <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
<!--            </xsl:if> -->
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tried setting the value of the newline variable to `&#x0A`, `&#x0D0A`, `&#10` and even using `<xsl:variable name='newline'><xsl:text>
</xsl:text></xsl:variable>`

Am I missing something here?
Thanks

Comment: Changing a file extension isn't going to change the contents of the file... are you loading the file into the same application?  If so, then is the application treating it differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the answer was to modify the value of the newline variable using both `x0D` and `x0A`.

Here is the variable newline:

```
<xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#x0D;&#x0A;'"/>
```

Hopefully this helps others having the same problem.